# how to get the applying element's index while using pandas apply function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to apply a simple function on a `pd.DataFrame` but I need the index of each element while applying.

Consider this `DataFrame`:

|  | CLM_1 | CLM_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | foo | bar |
| B | bar | foo |
| C | bar | foo |

and I want a `pd.Series` as result like so:

```
A    'A'
B    'B'
C    'D'
Length: 3, dtype: object
```

My approach:
I used `df.apply(lambda row: row.index, axis=1)` which obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `name` attribute of the applying row and it worked just fine! no need to add more columns to my DataFrame.
`df.apply(lambda row: row.name, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_series()` on the index:

```
>>> df.index.to_series()
A    A
B    B
C    C
dtype: object
```

If you want to use the index in a function, you can assign it as a column and then apply whatever function you need:

```
df["index"] = df.index
>>> df.apply(lambda row: row["CLM_1"]+row["index"], axis=1)
A    fooA
B    barB
C    barC
dtype: object
```

Comment: yes it works but I'm applying a different function and I need the index at applying time. to be more specific, I'm counting the occurrence of each index in a string.

Comment: That wasn't your question. Why not just assign a new column as index and then use it? See the edit.

Comment: that's what I wanted. thank you. but isn't there any better ways to access the index while applying functions? in JS for example, while using `Array.map` & `Array.foreach` we have access to the value and it's index at the same time.(`arr.map((item, index) => {...})`)

Comment: No idea about JS. This is how I would do it in Python.